# Django not showing group manage options in admin page

Tags: python, jquery, django, bootstrap-4

Recently, I deployed a Django web app. However, when I'm accessing the admin page, I'm not getting the expected interface to add or remove a user from a certain group:

[image]

At the of inspecting the page, I'm receiving the following messages:
[image]

any idea about how to handle these errros?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Content Security Policies are usually controlled via middleware like [django-csp](https://django-csp.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html). All the admin control JavaScript files are included as static files, no external libraries should be loaded, they should be on the same domain.

In order for CSP to allow to load these files, you need to add `script-src 'self'` (it's an alias for [same-origin](https://content-security-policy.com/self/)). Look inside `settings.py` for `CSP_SCRIPT_SRC` keyword and append `'self'` (single quotation marks are required).

Note: if CSP headers are added not by Django, but by reverse proxy, like nginx, then you should look and fix configuration settings there.